# lts 9.9 is associated with ghc 8.0.2. why does it use 8.0.1

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, stackage

I have a stack yaml with resolver lts-9.9 which is associated with ghc 8.0.2 (see https://www.stackage.org/lts-9.9 but when I run `stack solver` I see:

```
Using resolver: lts-9.9
Using compiler: ghc-8.0.1
```

and not ghc-8.0.2. This seems to violate that a stack build is constrained to exactly one set of packages and ghc? What do I overlook?

Comment: I was wondering whether the [`compiler-check` option](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration/#compiler-check) might be at play here, but even the `newer-minor` variant shouldn't allow this.

Comment: thanks - the compiler check helped. I wonder why exact match is not default; a miss on the compiler makesa package compiling on one machine not compiling on another - which is what stack wants to achieve.

Comment: So the documentation is wrong then? Could you maybe report this on `stack`'s issue tracker?

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if `ghc-8.0.1` is a system-based installed version of `ghc`, and `stack` is configured to use it instead of its own sandboxed version.

There is a pretty comprehensive page describing all the cases - https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/